# Using a type without template arguments as a template argument

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates

I have a class named `Registry` which correlates an ID with some data.
I would like to make it so the underlying structure which stores these pairs can be any `std::map`ish type, of which the user can define (e.g.: `std::map`, `std::unordered_map`).

My initial thought was to do something like this:

```cpp
template<typename Value, typename Container, typename ID = size_t>
class Registry{
    using Storage = Container<ID, value>;
    static_assert(std::is_same<Storage, std::map> || std::is_same<Storage, std::map>, "Underlying storage type must be a std::map-ish.");
    public:
    Storage<ID, Value> store;
    ...
```

However, trying to use the class results in an error:

```
Registry<bool, std::map> testRegistry;
err) argument list for class template std::map is missing
```

I understand the compiler's complaint, but is there any way to work around it so that this syntax (or something similar) might work?

Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare `Container` as a [template template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter). E.g.

```
template<typename Value, template <typename...> class Container, typename ID = size_t>
class Registry{

    using Storage = Container<ID, Value>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<Storage, std::map<ID, Value>> || std::is_same_v<Storage, std::unordered_map<ID, Value>>, "Underlying storage type must be a std::map-ish.");
    public:
    Storage store;
    ...
```

Other issues:

- `Storage` is an instantiation, so don't specify template arguments for it.
- Specify template arguments for `std::map`.
- As the condition of `static_assert` you should use `std::is_same_v` (or `std::is_same<...>::value` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I ended up using `template<class, class> class Container` as I only wanted two values as a parameter for the map type.

Comment: @Icedude_907 Answer revised.

Comment: @Icedude_907 containers like `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` have more than 2 template parameters, they are just defaulted, so you will need something more like `template<class, class, class...> class Container` to indicate that you require a type that takes *at least 2* template parameters but *can* take more.

Comment: Looks like this at the moment:
`template<typename Value, template <class, class, class ...> class Container, typename ID = size_t, typename ...ContainerExtras>`
`using Storage = Container<ID, Value, ContainerExtras...>;`

Answer (score 3):

As alternative, you might provide only container, instead of key, value, and template container:

```cpp
template <typename Container>
class Registry
{
    using ID = typename Container::key_type;
    using Value = typename Container::mapped_type;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<Container, std::map<ID, Value>>
               || std::is_same_v<Container, std::unordered_map<ID, Value>>,
                  "Underlying storage type must be a std::map-ish.");
    // ...
};
```

With usage

```cpp
Registry<std::map<std::size_t, bool>> testRegistry;
Registry<std::unordered_map<std::size_t, float>> testRegistry2;
```